An issue with print in R when followed by return and assignment
A minimal example is given at the bottom and it does work as expected.
Issue is when the returned table is assigned (see below), all the printing disappears.
(I am rendering as html in Quarto.)
a<-create_reactable(1:10)
dosomething(a)
b<-create_reactable(20:30)
dosomething(b)
c<-create_reactable(30:40)
dosomething(c)

What I am trying to do is having a little function that does some processing, prints the processed table and returns the processed table. (This function should later be used for calling from a loop)
{r}
# Load the reactable package
library(reactable)

# Define the function
create_reactable <- function(values) {
  # Create a data frame with values and their squares
  df <- data.frame(
    Column1 = values,
    Column3 = values^2
  )
  
  # Create the reactable
  table <- reactable(df)
  
  # Print the reactable
  print(reactable(df))
  
  # Return the reactable
  return(table)
}

# Call the function for different ranges
create_reactable(1:10)
create_reactable(20:30)
create_reactable(30:40)

I did come to realize that R handle return a little differently. However could not reach a solution that works with printing, return and assignment of return as outlined.
Please advise.
Expected output: 
Issue when assigned :

What do you mean by “R handle return a little differently”?  And what problem are you experiencing? I.e. what is the expected and the actual result from your code snippet at the bottom?

By 'little differently' I meant returning the last assigned even if there is no explicit return. Expected result is getting the three tables printed. create_reactable(1:10) print the table as expected. a<-create_reactable(1:10) do not print the table.

See this post to still print when assigning result to an object.

@julien.leroux5 ,  it worked for the invisible(x+1) as in that question. However for the invisible(table) in my case it did not work (i.e. the table was not printed. Let me see if I can update the question with a screenshot of the expected result)

right, invisible does not work in your case, but (a<-create_reactable(1:10)) works.

Expected and actual output added now.

@julien.leroux5, when enclosed () the print happens. I agree. But I doubt that it is not the print(table) from within the function that is printed. To illustrate , if we change the invisible return to the df instead of the table. do something like  {... invisible(df)}
(a<-create_reactable(1:10))
print(a), it is the df that is printed twice.

As you can see here, this is due to the way Quarto handles printing objects with the knitr package.
You can obtain your printed reactable objects by using the knit_print() function (after loading knitr with library(knitr)) instead of print.
As a general recommendation (see the discussion in answers of this post), you should probably print the objects once created, not directly in the function to create them, by calling knit_print outside the function:
a = create_reactable(1:10)
knit_print(a)



title: "Print From Function"
execute:
  echo: true
  eval: true
  warning:  false
format:
  html:
    css: style.css
---

```{r }
library(knitr)

fun <- function(df) {
  print(kable(df, format = "html", table.attr = 'class="scrollable-table"'))
  return(head(df,3))
}

create_reactable <- function(values) {
  df <- data.frame(
    Column1 = values,
    Column3 = values^2
  )
  fun(df)
}
```

```{r, output='asis'}
a<-create_reactable(1:10)
b<-create_reactable(20:30)
c<-create_reactable(30:40)
```

Above is the actual code that did produce the tables from within the function. Based on inputs from answer by @julien.leroux5. Please note the usage of output='asis' in the second chunk. Also had to use kable instead of reactable in the original question.

